# Meteor updating all records in user collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code tries to update all the records in the users collection but fails to do so. How can I fix it? thanks

```
Meteor.startup(function() {

  Meteor.users.update({}, {
    $unset: {
      'profile.taskInProgress': 1
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check documentation for mongoDB [$unset](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/)  operator:

> operator deletes a particular field

If you are trying to update values of tasks inProgress, use [$set](http://$set) operator instead.

Also make sure adding correct options: *{multi:true}*.
As per Meteor documentation for [Mongo.Collection#update](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Collection-update) default value of *multi* is *flase*.